# Likelihood that a given outcome was generated by a Markov model

Tags: monte-carlo, markov-process

I am new to the concept of Markov Models and Markov Chain Monte Carlo simulations.

I would like to take a piece of data and determine the likelihood that it was generated by a known MCMC model/generator that outputs similar data.

Is this possible, and if so, what is the term for what I'm describing?

#### Edit: More details as requested in comments

So let's say I have a MCMC generator that was initialized on a corpus of text by a certain author. I then have a given snippet of text and I want to know the probability / likelihood that the given snippet could be generated by the MCMC generator.

Comment: Can you provide some details about the MCMC generator?

Comment: @AlexR. I've edited the question with more information.

Comment: MCMC usually refers to algorithms that are designed to sample from some probability distribution by constructing a Markov chain (where the Markov chain is just a tool for sampling, not the model of a real-world phenomenon). Here it sounds like the Markov chain involved is the actual model, so I would not call this MCMC. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questiona/169518/

Comment: I'm eager to read more about this topic, but your link gives me a 404. Am I misusing the phrase MCMC? See my proposed answer for more details and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

As this question has received very little attention, I have done more research and I believe the best term for what I am describing here would be called: **Walk Probability**.

See, for example, the documentation for the Python package [Pykov](https://github.com/riccardoscalco/Pykov) - Specifically the method [`Pykov.Chain.walk_probability`](https://github.com/riccardoscalco/Pykov#walk_probabilitywalk).

I've added comments to an excerpt from the documentation to illustrate an example and the solution (in Python):

```
# Create a markov chain with 3 state tuples, and the probability of each.
# The state ['A','B'] has a probability of .3, P(['A','A']) = .7, etc.
>>> T = pykov.Chain({('A','B'): .3, ('A','A'): .7, ('B','A'): 1.})

# the Chain.walk_probability method will return log(P(given_chain))
>>> T.walk_probability(['A','A','B','A','A'])
-1.917322692203401
>>> probability = math.exp(-1.917322692203401)

>>> probability
0.147

# So the probability that the chain T would generate the walk
# ['A','A','B','A','A'] is equal to 0.147

>>> p = T.walk_probability(['A','B','B','B','A'])
>>> math.exp(p)
0.0

# And the probability that the same chain T would generate the walk
# ['A','B','B','B','A'] is 0, since the state tuple ('B','A') has a
# probability of 1.0 - the chain could never have generated
# the sequence ['B', 'B']
```

If anyone has a more rigorous answer based upon something other than the documentation of a random Python module, please contribute by adding an answer or editing this one!